# Access variable in for loop | Position current-1

Tags: python, jinja2

basically I want to do something like this in Jinja2 (this is C# Code):

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    Console.WriteLine(i-1)
    }
```

I already tried many versions of something like this:

```
    {% for value in list %}
    <p>{{value[loop.index-1]}}</p>
    {% endfor %}
```

To make the discussion easier let's say I have a list that contains this:

```py
{
  apples,
  peaches,
  oranges
}
```

I want to start counting up my list at peaches. But the first displayed value should show apples.

Since I work with large datasets that are generated from some special DB requests I can not alter them (since that would screw over my program).

Expected results would be something like this:

```
    {
    apples,
    peaches
    }
```

Is there a way to do this in Jinja2?
Please take into consideration that I am using flask and not jinja directly.

Have a nice day and thanks for your help :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The simplest way is to just use a slice that omits the last element:

```
for value in l[:-1]:
    # do something
```

You can also use a range that starts at 1, then subtract and use that as an index:

```
for index in range(1, len(l)):
    value = l[index-1]
```

Comment: The OP is asking about jinja templates,  not python

Comment: I don't know Jinga, but it's also tagged Python, I assumed it used Python syntax in the template's `{% for ... %}`.

Comment: This question is tagged with python too, because jinja2 is a templating engine that uses python. In addition to that my program (which contains a flask webserver) uses python.

Anyways:
Your answer helped me to solve my problem, thanks.

I did it like this in Jinja2:
`{% for val2 in key[:-1]%}`
   `<p>{{key}}<p>`
`{{% endfor %}}`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `{{val2}}`?

Comment: I already have a variable called `val` that why it is named `val2`. The name really is not that important.
And I actually need to work with my `key` in this case, not my `val2`. But you can always modify the code to show `val2` instead. I just needed a way to access the key/value that came before my current key/value.

Comment: But it's not `{{key}}`, that's the name of the list.

Comment: In my case my `key` is a list that contains another list. So everything is fine.

Comment: All I meant is that you shouldn't be printing the variable that contains the list, you should be printing the iteration variable.